# Java loop through array of array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have an array of an array:

```
double[][] img = new double[row][col];
```

and i want to loop through img in a 2x2 block... example:

```
2,  4, 31, 31   
3,  3, 21, 41
1,  2, 10, 20
3,  2, 20, 30
```

then you start by looking at the first 2x2 sub-array (from the top-left)

```
2,  4
3,  3
```

We then look at the next 2x2 block

```
31,  31
21,  41
```

other blocks would be 1,2,3,2 and 10,20,20,30...

How do make a loop so it goes through like this? Essentially I am doing this so I can find the average of the values in the block, and replace each element in the array by that average.

Comment: We'll write the code for you, but we're idiots here, so first you have to supply us with a step-by-step set of instructions for how to navigate through the array.

Comment: class Pixels {
 
 int row = 4;
 int col = 4;
 double[][] matrix  = new double[row][col];
 
 public double[][] block() {
  for (int i=0; i < 2; i++) {
   for(int j = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    
   }
  }
  return matrix;
  
 }

}

Comment: @HotLicks I am asking for the HOW TO not the code... I can code myself... thanks...

Comment: @choloboy7 tell that to all the people who already wrote a code implementation for you =\ (hoping to earn *easy* rep)

Comment: @choloboy7 Don't post code ass comment. Try to format it and add it to question with [[edit]] option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this help you:

```
tile = 2;
for(i = 0; i < row; i = tile + i)
 for(j = 0; j < col; j= tile + j)
  for(r = 0; r < tile; r++)   
    for(c = 0; c < tile; c++) 
      System.out.print(" " + img[i+r][j+c]);
    System.out.print("\n");
```

put `tile` size if your need other size then  2*2:

**EDIT**
Now I am providing complete code.

```
class BreakWithLabelDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] img = { 
                    {55, 60, 65, 1},
                    {95, 90, 85, 5},
                    {5,  0,  8,  5},  
                    {53, 60, 89, -5}
        };


        int tile=2; 
        int row=4; 
        int col=4;
        int i, r;
        int j, c;

        tile = 2;
        for(i = 0; i < row; i= tile + i)
           for(j = 0; j < col; j= tile + j){
              for(r = 0; r < tile; r++){   
                 for(c = 0; c < tile; c++) 
                    System.out.print(" ", img[i+r][j+c]);
                 System.out.println("");
              }
              System.out.println("\n");
           }



        int img2[][] = { 
                  // 1   2   3   4  5  6  7  8  9 
                    {55, 60, 65, 1, 2, 4, 1, 4, 0},
                    {95, 90, 85, 5, 3, 6, 5, 0, 8},
                    {5,  0,  8,  5,-1, 2, 2, 5, 6},  
                    {95, 90, 85, 5, 3, 6, 5, 0, 8},
                    {55, 60, 65, 1, 2, 4, 1, 4, 0},
                    {5,  0,  8,  5,-1, 2, 2, 5, 6},  
                    {1,  2,  3,  4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, 
                    {1,  2,  3,  4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, 
                    {1,  2,  3,  4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
                  };

         row = 9; 
         col = 9;
         tile = 3;

         for(i = 0; i < row; i= tile + i)
           for(j = 0; j < col; j= tile + j){
              for(r = 0; r < tile; r++){   
                 for(c = 0; c < tile; c++) 
                    System.out.print(" ", img[i+r][j+c]);
                 System.out.println("");
              }
              System.out.println("\n");
           }
    }
}
```

This is actually working:

A running instance

```
 55  60 
 95  90 


 65   1 
 85   5 


  5   0 
 53  60 


  8   5 
 89  -5 


 55  60  65 
 95  90  85 
  5   0   8 


  1   2   4 
  5   3   6 
  5  -1   2 


  1   4   0 
  5   0   8 
  2   5   6 


 95  90  85 
 55  60  65 
  5   0   8 


  5   3   6 
  1   2   4 
  5  -1   2 


  5   0   8 
  1   4   0 
  2   5   6 


  1   2   3 
  1   2   3 
  1   2   3 


  4   5   6 
  4   5   6 
  4   5   6 


  7   8   9 
  7   8   9 
  7   8   9
```

Comment: so to iterate through a 2x2 grid style, i need make 4 loops? two loops  doesnt cut it?

Comment: @choloboy7 Not nearness. your can do like Kevin DiTraglia says. But In CASE instead of 2*2 you need something else then this way is good like 4*4

Comment: so with this method if title gets changed to 3, then im saying im working with a 3*3?

Comment: then in put `tile = 3` but cation row and colomn should be multiple of 3 otherwise exception may rise

Comment: @choloboy7 Sorry Choloboy earlier I made mistake now it will work as your desired. Let me know if  any confutation. Update code

Comment: thanks for the assistance... although it gives me array out of bounds exception

Comment: @choloboy7 Yes it will I have not run it. But functional wise its good go here http://codepad.org/7c7pigHD

Comment: @choloboy7 there must be small error i made while writing. So fo try with first do once.

Answer (score 3):

You will need two nested `for` loops.  But unlike normal `for` loops, instead of incrementing your looping variables, in both cases, add 2 to your index.  Then, inside the inner for loop, assuming you have looping indexes `i` and `j`, refer to your 4 values with `img[i][j]`, `img[i + 1][j]`, `img[i][j + 1]`, and `img[i + 1][j + 1]`.  But you'll have to be careful if `row` or `col` is odd.

Comment: what do you mean by if row and col are odd? thanks for the answer btw

Comment: If either `row` or `col` are odd, then either `i + 1` or `j + 1` will run off the end of the array with an error; you will probably need to handle this situation.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a structure like this:

```
double[][] img = new double[row][col];
//This will break if row or col are odd, make sure you are always passing an even amount or check for this case.
for (int i = 0; i < row; i+=2) {
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j+=2) {
        //Do what you need with these values:
        img[i][j];     //Top left
        img[i+1][j];   //Top right
        img[i][j+1];   //Bottom left
        img[i+1][j+1]; //Bottom right
    }
}
```

Comment: the four img's denoted in your answer, are those how to call the elements in my "grid"?

Comment: @choloboy7 each of those 4 values will be a value you in the 2x2 grid you are hunting for: `img[i][j]` = top left; `img[i+1][j]` = top right; `img[i][j+1]` = bottom left; `img[i+1][j+1]` = bottom right.